Zabbix server db error no such file or directory
We have configured zabbix monitoring tool on linux server  Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.4  server.
Intermittently we are getting error as db not found  when we access the zabbix server url nms.digisapi.in
in logs we have found below logs
] Received SHUTDOWN from user . Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.39-0ubuntu0.24.04.1).
2024-09-04T07:35:14.448479Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010909] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 16  user: 'zabbix'.
Intermittently we are getting db not found error as part of troubleshooting we have implemented below steps.
a) we have configured socket path as  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock in config file " /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysql.conf" and also in zabbix config file " etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf "
b) increased innodb_buffer_pool_size from 128MB to 300MB
please help in finding permanent solution for this
